# Bermuda missing from S&P's list of Withholding Tax Rates - what's the rate?

Tags: united-states, foreign-income, stock-dividend

S&P Dow Jones publishes a list of Witholding Tax Rates by country [here](https://www.spglobal.com/spdji/en/documents/additional-material/withholding-tax-index-values.pdf).

For some reason, Bermuda is not on this list.

What is the rate for Bermuda?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bermuda is not an independent country but a British Overseas Territory.

[This page](https://taxsummaries.pwc.com/bermuda/corporate/withholding-taxes) from PricewaterhouseCoopers says that "there are no withholding taxes in Bermuda".  Whether that is enough for you is for you to decide.